# Swagger-UI doesn't recognize application/hal+json

Tags: java, spring, rest, swagger, swagger-ui

I have RESTful API for a Spring Boot application. I ran into this when I was trying to figure out a separate issue that involved trying to add custom media-types.

After trying to do this I got a `HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptable` exception when I try to view my API documentation. This exception is visible only in the logs (if I turn the level up to `DEBUG`). On the browser I see `406 undefined`. Here's a screenshot:

[image]

The exception I get from Spring Boot's logs is this:

```
2014-11-04 10:08:26.189 DEBUG 5496 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolving exception from handler [public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<com.wordnik.swagger.model.ResourceListing> com.mangofactory.swagger.controllers.DefaultSwaggerController.getResourceListing(java.lang.String)]: org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException: Could not find acceptable representation
```

The root of the problem is that the existing, producible-media-types are overwritten.

Without the code above, the list contains:

- `application/hal+json`
- `application/json;charset=UTF-8`
- `application/*+json;charset=UTF-8`.

With my changes, the list only contains `application/hal+json` and my custom media-type. So what happens is that Spring cannot find a compatible media-type at all because Swagger UI has `application/json` in its `Accept:` header whereas `http://localhost:8080/api-docs` vends `application/hal+json` (I verified using curl):

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: 0
X-Frame-Options: DENY
X-Application-Context: application
Content-Type: application/hal+json
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Date: Tue, 04 Nov 2014 16:56:57 GMT
```

I'm guessing that Swagger UI should probably set the accept header to `application/json,application/hal+json` or perhaps use a wildcard like `application/*+json`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current solution would be to update swagger-client.js - The part where the SwaggerClient is built, it is hard coded with application/json as the mime type.

The current line of code is https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/blob/master/dist/lib/swagger-client.js#L335 though that may obviously change in different versions (so may not be relevant in the future when reading this answer).

The swagger-client.js exists in two places - the /dist/lib dir for the pre-built application or directly under the /lib dir for the build process. You should change the value depending on what you're using.

Comment: This does fix the problem for the time being. Thanks a bunch! I still need to figure out why all those other message converters are being blown away as well.

Comment: The link is broken in the current version. Does anyone have a fix for the current version?

Comment: @MichalPaszkiewicz - the code has shifted significantly since (should have used a link to a direct hash, my apologies). Finding the location now would take me a bit, though I'm not sure the problem still exists with the current version.